# Django ManyToManyField post not working in drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

model

```
class DesignerProduct(models.Model):
    title      = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=None)
    descripton = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=None)
    price      = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=None)
    editions   = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=None)
    verified   = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    user       = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Login, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="designerproduct", null=True, blank=True
    )
    collection = models.ForeignKey(
        to=DesignerCollection, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="designerproduct", null=True, blank=True
    )
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(DesignerCategories, related_name='designerproduct', blank=True)
```

serializers

```
class DesignerProductSeriali
    designerproductmedia = DesignerProductMediaSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Login.objects.all(), many=False)
    collection = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=DesignerCollection.objects.all(), many=False)

    user_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.name', read_only=True)
    user_photo = serializers.CharField(source='user.display_photo', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = DesignerProduct
        fields = ('id', "user", "categories", "collection", 'created_at', 'designerproductmedia', 'title', 'descripton', 'price', 'editions', 'verified', 'user_name', 'user_photo')
        depth = 1
```

data after upload

```
    {
        "id": 11,
        "user": 9,
        "categories": [],
        "collection": 6,
        "created_at": "2021-06-05T17:03:52.807755Z",
        "designerproductmedia": [
            {
                "file": "designer/products/74647.jpg",
                "id": "38",
                "firework": null
            }
        ],
        "title": "hello there",
        "descripton": "hello there",
        "price": "10",
        "editions": "10",
        "verified": false,
        "user_name": "soubhagya pradhan",
        "user_photo": "profile/52319.jpg"
    }
```

Here i am omplmenting django manyToMany relation
and sending categories like [1, 2, 3]
But, after successfull post category list comes empty .

How to fix that ?

Please take a look

[image]
In drf also not showing please check this image

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a method `get_categories` by defining `categories` as `SerializerMethodField` to fetch the `categories` related to each instance of `DesignerProduct`.

Make these changes to your serializer -

```
class DesignerProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    categories = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    designerproductmedia = DesignerProductMediaSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Login.objects.all(), many=False)
    collection = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=DesignerCollection.objects.all(), many=False)

    user_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.name', read_only=True)
    user_photo = serializers.CharField(source='user.display_photo', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = DesignerProduct
        fields = ('id', "user", "categories", "collection", 'created_at', 'designerproductmedia', 'title', 'descripton', 'price', 'editions', 'verified', 'user_name', 'user_photo')
        depth = 1

    def get_categories(self, obj):
       category_list = []
       category_list.append(category.id) [for category in obj.categories.all()]
       return category_list
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to successfully send `POST` requests, you must add the `categories` field to your serializer as per below:

```
categories = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    queryset=DesignerCategories.objects.all(), many=True
)
```